# How to set background of an spinner dialog

Tags: android, android-layout, android-dialog

Hi I want to set the background for the dialog of my spinner. I am using following code

```
    <Spinner android:id="@+id/my_ac_debt_card_spinner"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/my_ac_debt_card_text" android:entries="@array/my_ac_debt_array"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dip" android:layout_marginLeft="50dip"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/my_ac_spinner_bg" android:paddingLeft="5dip"
        android:gravity="center_vertical" android:popupBackground="@drawable/my_ac_round_rect"/>
```

Java code is like this:

```
    Spinner spin = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.my_ac_debt_card_spinner);
            final ArrayAdapter<String> a = new SpinnerAdapter(
                    getActivity(),
                    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,
                    debit_array);
            spin.setAdapter(a);
```

But I am not able to set background of the popup dialog.
Can anyone please help me to solve this issue.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hey, digging a very old post... were you able to make it ?

Answer (score 0):

Try putting this code into your ListAdapter for the Spinner in getDropDownView:

```
if (parent != null && parent instanceof ListView) {
        ((ListView) parent).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.background);
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Try changing

```
android:popupBackground="@drawable/my_ac_round_rect" to
```

to

```
android:background="@drawable/my_ac_round_rect"
```

Also, here's a good blog I found on customizing a spinner:  http://www.gersic.com/blog.php?id=57